# Getting "ValueError: substring not found" when trying to parse gzipped CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am new in python. I am getting Error in the line

```
headline = csv_str[:csv_str.index('\n')];
```

Error is:

> ValueError: substring not found

I do not know, why it is coming? I search google, however, could not find the solution? Here is the complete code

```
# This is a sample Python script.

# Press Shift+F10 to execute it or replace it with your code.
# Press Double Shift to search everywhere for classes, files, tool windows, actions, and settings.

import matplotlib as mpl;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import numpy as np;
import gzip;
# import StringIO; Udated one is below
# import io.StringIO
from io import StringIO


def parse_header_of_csv(csv_str):
    # Isolate the headline columns: int(csv_str.index('\n'))
    headline = csv_str[:csv_str.index('\n')];
    columns = headline.split(',');

    # The first column should be timestamp:
    assert columns[0] == 'timestamp';
    # The last column should be label_source:
    assert columns[-1] == 'label_source';

    # Search for the column of the first label:
    for (ci, col) in enumerate(columns):
        if col.startswith('label:'):
            first_label_ind = ci;
            break;
        pass;

    # Feature columns come after timestamp and before the labels:
    feature_names = columns[1:first_label_ind];
    # Then come the labels, till the one-before-last column:
    label_names = columns[first_label_ind:-1];
    for (li, label) in enumerate(label_names):
        # In the CSV the label names appear with prefix 'label:', but we don't need it after reading the data:
        assert label.startswith('label:');
        label_names[li] = label.replace('label:', '');
        pass;

    return (feature_names, label_names);


def parse_body_of_csv(csv_str, n_features):
    # Read the entire CSV body into a single numeric matrix:
    full_table = np.loadtxt(StringIO.StringIO(csv_str), delimiter=',', skiprows=1);

    # Timestamp is the primary key for the records (examples):
    timestamps = full_table[:, 0].astype(int);

    # Read the sensor features:
    X = full_table[:, 1:(n_features + 1)];

    # Read the binary label values, and the 'missing label' indicators:
    trinary_labels_mat = full_table[:, (n_features + 1):-1];  # This should have values of either 0., 1. or NaN
    M = np.isnan(trinary_labels_mat);  # M is the missing label matrix
    Y = np.where(M, 0, trinary_labels_mat) > 0.;  # Y is the label matrix

    return (X, Y, M, timestamps);


'''
Read the data (precomputed sensor-features and labels) for a user.
This function assumes the user's data file is present.
'''


def read_user_data(uuid):
    user_data_file = '%s.features_labels.csv.gz' % uuid;

    # Read the entire csv file of the user:
    with gzip.open(user_data_file, 'rt') as fid:
        csv_str = fid.read();
        pass;

    (feature_names, label_names) = parse_header_of_csv(csv_str);
    n_features = len(feature_names);
    (X, Y, M, timestamps) = parse_body_of_csv(csv_str, n_features);

    return (X, Y, M, timestamps, feature_names, label_names);


def print_hi(name):
    # Use a breakpoint in the code line below to debug your script.
    print(f'Hi, {name}')  # Press Ctrl+F8 to toggle the breakpoint.


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uuid = '1155FF54-63D3-4AB2-9863-8385D0BD0A13';
    (X, Y, M, timestamps, feature_names, label_names) = read_user_data(uuid);

# See PyCharm help at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/
```

**TracBack**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1448, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Nafees Ahmed/PycharmProjects/Extra_Sensory_Experimetns/main.py", line 92, in <module>
    (X, Y, M, timestamps, feature_names, label_names) = read_user_data(uuid);
  File "C:/Users/Nafees Ahmed/PycharmProjects/Extra_Sensory_Experimetns/main.py", line 77, in read_user_data
    (feature_names, label_names) = parse_header_of_csv(csv_str);
  File "C:/Users/Nafees Ahmed/PycharmProjects/Extra_Sensory_Experimetns/main.py", line 17, in parse_header_of_csv
    headline = csv_str[:csv_str.index('\n')];
ValueError: substring not found
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation.

Comment: @Barmar I edited question with full traceback. You may see.

Comment: The error message says `int(csv_str.index('\n'))` That doesn't appear in the code anywhere.

Comment: The problem is that `csv_str` is a byte array, not a string, so it doesn't contain characters and you can't search for the index of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gzip.open()` uses binary mode by default, so `csv_str` is a byte string, not a string. Open the file in text mode to get ordinary strings. Change

```
with gzip.open(user_data_file, 'r') as fid:
```

to

```
with gzip.open(user_data_file, 'rt') as fid:
```

Also, instead of writing your own code to parse the CSV file, I suggest you use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above, your error message doesn't match the code you posted. Please post the actual code (with correct indentation) and the corresponding error message.

Comment: Now I copied code from editor and pasted here. Please check

Comment: You're getting a completely different error now.

Comment: That error means there's no newline in the file.

Comment: Check the file with a hex dump, see what character is being used as the line delimiter.

Comment: Why don't you just use the csv module like I suggested?

Comment: Yes, issue is solved. Thanks a lot. Please rate my question also. It will open the door for future queries. Once again Thanks a lot.

Comment: actually I am using someone code and do not want to change. I am just using for learning

Answer (score 0):

`gzip.open` opens its argument in binary mode by default, which means its `read` method returns a `bytes` object.

Because of that, the argument to `csv_str.index` must *also* be a `bytes` object:

```
headline = csv_str[:csv_str.index(b'\n')]
```

Comment: Alternatively he could open in text mode so he doesn't need to convert between bytes and strings.

Comment: That's probably the better solution; I just chose to focus on the easier-to-point-out one.

Comment: @Barmar What should be the solution?